# regex:pattern validation in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation

I try validate facebook.com url in Laravel.
this is my regex:

```
    'facebook' => 'url|regex:((?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*))|nullable',
```

It's work in online regex tests website (https://regex101.com/), but in `Laravel`. I have error

> "preg_match(): No ending matching delimiter ')' found".

what is the problem?

Comment: seems. you should write it `regex:/.../`

Comment: i try, and result : "preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found"

Comment: 'facebook' => 'url|regex:/((?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*))/|nullable'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this note in the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation):

> When using the regex / not_regex patterns, it may be necessary to
>   specify rules in an array instead of using pipe delimiters, especially
>   if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

So, this should work:

```
'facebook' => ['url', 'regex:/(?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?(?:profile.php\?id=(?=\d.*))?([\w\-]*))/', 'nullable']
```

Comment: error    "preg_match(): Compilation failed: assertion expected after (?( or (?(?C) at offset 51"

Comment: Seems like you had an extra `(` in your pattern. Can you give it a try now?